# How to split a MCQs(multiple choice questions) string using regular expression

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string which I extracted from a pdf document.
here is the string...

"1.
The first Chief editor of 'Swadesabhimani':
(A) Vakkom Abdul Khadar Maulavi (C) K. Ramakrishna Pillai
(B) Sir. C.P. Govinda Pillai (D) G. Parameswaran Pillai
2.
"Mitra mela', a secret society was organized by :
(A) B.G. Tilak (C) Madan Lal Dhingra
(B) Sachin Sanya (D) Savarkar
3.
The 'Lekshamveedu' scheme was launched by :
(A) A.K. Gopalan (C) Pattom. A. Thanupillai
(B) E.K. Nayanar (D) M.N. Govindan Nair
4.
The Act relating to water (Prevention and Control of Pollution): (A) 1974
(B) 1981 (C) 2002
(D) 1986
The expanded form of NFAI:
(A) National Film Award of India (B) The National Film Academy of India (C) The National Film Archive of India (D) The National Film Authority of India
6.
Which of the following legislations banned Sati and made it illegal?
(A) Act of 1870 (B) Sharada Act of 1930 (C) Bengal Regulation Act of 1795 (D) Regulation Act XVII of December 1829
7
Liber
Liberator of Indian Press was :
(A) Charles Metcalfe (C) John Adams
(B) Lord Wellesley (D) Lord Hastings"

**The problem is**

1) The question number for the fifth question is missing.

2) sixth has a question mark (?) instead of (:) at the end of the question

3) seventh is missing the dot (.) after question number

my desired output is separate strings for each question-options set
e.g.

"1.
The first Chief editor of 'Swadesabhimani':
(A) Vakkom Abdul Khadar Maulavi (C) K. Ramakrishna Pillai
(B) Sir. C.P. Govinda Pillai (D) G. Parameswaran Pillai"

"2.
"Mitra mela', a secret society was organized by :
(A) B.G. Tilak (C) Madan Lal Dhingra
(B) Sachin Sanya (D) Savarkar"

and so on...

here is what I have tried

1.

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[0-9][.][a-zA-Z0-9]*");
String[] s=p.split(mcqString);
```

2.

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[0-9][.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*[:|?][a-zA-Z0-9]*");
String[] s=p.split(mcqString);
```

And other combinations, But nothing works fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions all contain parts with `([A-Z])`

Instead of split, one option is to match all the parts that do not start with the parenthesis. Then match all following that don't start with parenthesis.

```
^(?:(?!\([A-Z]\)).*\R)+(?:\([A-Z]\).*\R*)+
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!\([A-Z]\))` Negative lookahead, assert on the right is not a char A-Z between `()`
  - `.*\R` Match any char except a newline and a unicode newline sequence
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to get at least 1 line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\([A-Z]\).*\R*` Match a char A-Z between `()`, 1+ times any char and an optional unicode newline sequence
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to get at least 1 line

In Java

```
final String regex = "^(?:(?!\\([A-Z]\\)).*\\R)+(?:\\([A-Z]\\).*\\R*)+";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H56KKl/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/KieYGn)